# Decomposing a touch gesture into multiple main points in android studio

Tags: android, gesture

I want to be able to decompose a long gestures (the touch finger remains on the screen until the gesture ends) into multiple main points in order to measure and store the pressure and velocity between each one of them as shown in an example gesture in [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3U9b.png).
I am also open to other approaches that would allow me to get a similar result.

Comment: see `android.view.MotionEvent` and  `android.view.VelocityTracker` documentation

Comment: and? what kind of problems do you have with those classes?

Comment: My problem is that i cant find an algorithm or a method to implement the desired task, i want an example or a similar approach in order to have a clear idea about the matter

Comment: what algorithm? you have a bunch of `MotionEvent`s right? so simply feed your `VelocityTracker` with the events and call `computeCurrentVelocity` when needed

Comment: But what i want to know is how to differentiate between the end of the first part of the gesture (line between a and b) and the the second part of the gesture ( curve between b and c) and measure the velocity and pressure between each each part seperately.

Comment: there is no such thing like first and second part - who says there are any parts on that gesture? are those parts divided by some finger up/down gestures?

Comment: I want to divide that gesture into those parts

Comment: how? is your finger lifted up? if no, so how can you divide them?

Comment: No with my finger pressed down the entire time, thats what i want to know... Thats why i asked this question

Comment: ok so maybe it has not two parts but maybe seven? how do you know its only two of them?

Comment: When the touch input changes direction (for example when the movement changes from up to down)  this could be considered the end of the first part and the start of the second one like it is shown in the image i attached, the first part is a till b then when the movement changes it is considered a second part ( b till c)

Comment: so use `VelocityTracker` and call `computeCurrentVelocity` on every event - then you will be able to campare the current and previous velocities

Comment: My problem is not here, my problem is how can i divide this gesture into the mentioned part, is there a way to detect such a change in movement that would allow me to divide my gesture to parts?

Comment: yes, by comparing the velocities

Comment: Is there a code that would guide me in this procedure? If so kindly supply me with a link.

Comment: i dont have any